# Hexadecimal Convertor for Python String Overloader

Tags: python, string, hex, operator-overloading

I am making a hexadecimal convertor class that requires a string operator over loader. When I run the tester program against my actual program, the str() crashes the program. I tried printing out the actual string to see where I went wrong, but all that was printed was blank lines. The tester program gives me a 90.0/100.0 because the string over loader isn't working.
[Python code for hex convertor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMCXk.png) [Updated Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMCXk.png)

```
class Hexadecimal:
    def __init__(self, decimal = "1128"):
        if type(decimal) is int:
            if decimal >= 0:
                self.__decimal = decimal
            else:
                raise ValueError ("Must be greater than zero.")
        elif type(decimal) is list:
            raise ValueError ("Cannot enter lists.")
        elif type(decimal) is float:
            decimal = int(decimal)
            if decimal >= 0:
                self.__decimal = decimal
            else:
                raise ValueError ("Cannot have negative floats.")

        elif type(decimal) is str:

            if decimal not in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]:  
                decimal = float(decimal)
            else:
                raise ValueError ("Cannot convert string to float.")

        else:
            self.__decimal = int(decimal)


    #Overloaded string function      
    def __str__(self):
        h_string = ""
        number = self.__decimal
        while number > 0:
            digit = number % 16
            number //= 16

            if digit < 10 and digit > 0:
                h_string += str(digit) 


            elif digit == 10:
                h_string += "A"


            elif digit == 11:
                h_string += "B"

            elif digit == 12:
                h_string += "C"

            elif digit == 13:
                h_string += "D"

            elif digit == 14:
                h_string += "E"

            elif digit == 15:
                h_string += "F"




            print(h_string[::-1])
        return h_string[::-1]
```

Result:
Crashed when testing str().
A
A
F
F
A
A
2
32
2
32
A
A
9
19
9
19
3
3
1
1
4
4
2
2
4
4
1
1
90.0

Comment: You should include the code as text in the body of your question. Why are you suppressing the errors?  Remove the `try/except`, and then read the error messages.  They will tell you what's going wrong

Comment: Why are you doing `(number % 16) * 16`? The two operations you need are *division* and *remainder*. Note, there'a a handy built-in function, `divmod(x)` that returns this pair ...

Comment: I removed them, and it is still coming up with the same result.

Comment: Removing the try:except: won't change the answer, but it will allow you to study the traceback to see why the program is failing.

Comment: `When I run the tester program against my actual program, the str() crashes the program.` You could make it easier for people to help by providing an [mcve].